# Remove White Spaces from Rows MySql Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a slight problem i merged 3 tables into 1 using PHP which worked fine but on 1 of the rows i have somehow incorporated a white-space at the begging of the data, which is now causing some major problems for me.

Is there any other way to remove the White-space without going in and out of php and MySql?

there are 48,000,000 records that need changing and using php to trim the string of each one will take weeks and slow my server down considerably, so i am looking for a better solution is there is one.

Thanks For the Help

Comment: If it is just one row, why you don't you just manually edit that row?

Comment: @thatidiotguy it is clearly mentioned in the question that there are 48,000,000 records

Answer (score 5):

If you know the extra white-space(s) is only at the beginning of the data, then you can do this:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET    column = LTRIM(column)
WHERE  column LIKE ' %'
```

This will still be able to utilize an index set up on `column` if you have done so.

Answer (score 3):

```
update your_table
set some_column = substring(some_column, 1)
where substring(some_column, 1, 1) =  ' '
```